# Use a jar with source as source for jdb?

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I have a executable jar with source compiled in and I want to debug it using jdb (no other debugger available in this environment unfortunately).

I am able to debug it with

```
jdb -classpath "${JAR_FILE}:${CLASS_PATH}" ${MAIN_CLASS} ${ARGS}
```

How can I get jdb to use the source that is built into the jar file?

**Notes:** Java 6, AIX, ksh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be possible, as stated in [this (very old) post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=676631) on the forums.

Comment: Nice. Source code for jdb appears to explicitly ignore *.jar and *.zip entries for `sourcepath`.

Comment: @kschneid, Thanks for checking.  Stick around, we need more like you.

Comment: @kschneid Now that Oracle has taken over Sun, I'm having difficulty locating a link for the jdb source code :-(, but I'll take you at your word.  Lame.

Comment: And apparently Oracle saw fit to purge their very old forum posts.  Link is now broken. :'(

Answer (score 8):

If jdb is ignoring *.jar and *.zip entries for `sourcepath`, maybe you can whip up a batchfile to expand the source from the target jar into a temp directory and point `sourcepath` to that.

Something like this

```
MYDEBUGDIR=/temp/source/mydebug
jar -xf target.jar -C $MYDEBUGDIR
jdb -sourcepath ${MYDEBUGDIR} -classpath "${JAR_FILE}:${CLASS_PATH}" ${MAIN_CLASS} ${ARGS}
rmdir -r $MYDEBUGDIR
```

That way the debug source is in sync with the jar and it cleans up after itself.

Answer (score 1):

actually I managed to debug into a jar file without source code today, the steps are as follows:

1. unzip jar file
2. jdb -sourcepath [unzipped source folder] -classpath [the path for your main class]
3. after jdb initializing, excute:

```
stop at <package>.<yourclass>:<linenunmber>
run <your main class, for example org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher>
```

4. after breakpoint triggered, you can step by step debug using jdb command

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this personally, but perhaps the `sourcepath` option will allow JAR files: `jdb -sourcepath ${JAR_FILE} ...`